# Ordering of gganimate numeric transition

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm sitting with a tiny frustrating problem with gganimate.

I'd like to illustrate the improvement of various metrics while fitting model parameters. However, I can't figure how to force frames to be ordered according to metrics being maximized or minimized.
Take a simple example. We'll fit a OLS model on `mtcars` using `mpg` as reponse and `hp` and explanatory variable (polynomial for better fit). An alternative is the empty model. I would like to illustrate how residual-sum-squared decreases as the model parameters transition towards their MLE values. This is fairly simple, just generate some data to visualize `geom_line` for each value of RSS along the chosen parameters. But to illustrate this better I'd like the title to show the decreasing value for RSS and the image to start from the empty model. I can achieve the latter by reversing the sign of rss, or I can visualize the Rss change, but I cant seem to get both. How do I achieve this

```
###
# Data generation for plot (start)
###
# import data
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
data(mtcars)
# Find MLE's
fit <- lm(mpg ~ poly(hp, 2, raw = TRUE), data = mtcars)
# Generate matrix of parameter matrix from empty model to polynomial MLE model
startcoef <- c(mean(mtcars$mpg), 0, 0)
coefs <- sapply(1:3, function(i)seq(startcoef[i], coef(fit)[i], length = 100))
colnames(coefs) <- names(coef(fit))
RSS <- function(coefs)
  sum((mtcars$mpg - (coefs[1] + coefs[2] * mtcars$hp + coefs[3] * mtcars$hp^2))^2)

# Generate line data for each value of RSS
hp_seq <- seq(min(mtcars$hp), max(mtcars$hp), length = 100)
plot_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i, x = hp_seq, n = length(hp_seq)){
  cbind(hp = hp_seq, 
        mpg = cbind(1, hp_seq, hp_seq^2) %*% coefs[i, 1:3], 
        rss = rep(RSS(coefs[i, ]), n),
        id = rep(i, n))
}))
plot_data <- as.data.frame(plot_data)
names(plot_data) <- c('hp', 'mpg', 'rss', 'id')
###
# Data generation for plot (end)
###
# Generate gif:
p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_line(col = 'blue') + 
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg), data = mtcars, inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  transition_manual(rss) + 
  ease_aes('linear') + 
  labs(title = 'RSS: {current_frame}')
animate(p, duration = 10, rewind = FALSE, start_pause = 5, end_pause = 5, 
        renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Does `p <- ggplot(plot_data %>% mutate(rss = as.character(rss) %>% forcats::fct_rev()), aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + ...` do what you want?

Comment: In the simple reproducible example it does, but causes complications if `rss` itself is used as a numeric variable across various geoms. Of course there are work arounds duplicating columns or data, but it seems this should be simple to achieve.

Comment: Then what about `p <- ggplot(plot_data %>% mutate(rss2 = as.character(rss) %>% forcats::fct_rev()), aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +` ... `transition_manual(rss2) +` ... ?   The point is you can make an indexing variable that has the title or title data you want, but as a factor so it is ordered like you want. None of the current transition functions in `gganimate` support ordering in reverse from the start. If this would be a useful option I suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues